# Double Possessive - two friends of hers

Tags: double-possessives

> The train arrived at the station, and Paula got off. Two friends of hers, Jon and Rachel, were waiting to meet her.

I understand why I should say 'a friend of hers' instead of 'her a friend'. But here I cannot understand why 'two friends of hers' is used instead of 'her two friends'. Please explain why.

Comment: I don't follow you. You can't say "my a friend". "Two friends of hers"  does not mean the same as "two of my friends". I think you need to rethink your question.

Comment: I don't know why you keep switching between ***hers*** and ***my***. It would be possible to say ***Two of her friends** [were waiting]* (or ***two of my friends***) instead of ***two friends of hers*** (or ***two friends of mine***). In most contexts the two forms are equivalent and interchangeable. You could also use ***Her two friends** [, Jon and Rachel,] **were waiting*** in your context with *almost* the same meaning (not quite, because that version tends to imply either that she only has two friends, OR only those two *particular* friends are relevant to the broader narrative context).

Comment: That was my mistake. I modified 'my' to 'her' now. I'm sorry.

Comment: Is 'two friends of hers' an idiomatic expression?

Comment: Yes - it's idiomatic to *always* use the ***possessive*** form of the pronoun (***of hers / of mine*** rather than ***of her / of me***). But that "double possessive" is *optional* when used with a proper noun and the Saxon genitive, so ***Two friends of Peter*** and ***Two friends of Peter's*** are both perfectly idiomatic. See my question [Why is it usually “friend of his”, but no possessive apostrophe with “friend of Peter”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50588/) over on ELU for further discussion about this.

Comment: (It's irrelevant that all the above examples feature plural ***friends***. Exactly the same applies with ***a friend of Peter*** and ***a friend of Peter's***, which are both fine.)

Answer (score 1):

**Two friends of hers** were waiting. implies:

They are two of what could be other friends or other types of relationships.

- Two members of my family. The of often signals some kind of group (group of friends, group of family members)

**Her two friends** is much more specific because it **could imply** those are her only friends.

- **Two friends of mine** speak Italian. Three do not. [i.e. in or from my group of friends]
- **My two friends** speak Italian. That suggests I only have two friends.

[There is no double possessive.]

Comment: +1 Quite so. Although neither explicitly states her total number of friends, the usage of the phrases strongly suggests these interpretations.